# GUID/UUID compatibility issue between .NET and Linux

Tags: c++, .net, linux, guid, uuid

In my c++ program, I am generating a uuid value using debian linux's uuid package, it's returning me an unsigned char array of size 16, which is of type uuid_t. Then I convert it to string and print it to the console.

Then I take the same byte array and send it to a windows machine over the network. Windows machine uses .net's GUID type, and creates a GUID object using the same byte array. Then I use ToString method of the GUID to print it to the console again. Surprisingly same byte array has different string representations under Linux and .Net, even though they are almost similar.

Here's an example:

Byte array:

101,208,176,173,236,192,64,86,191,214,132,2,213,232,143,247

Linux:
65d0b0ad-ecc0-4056-bfd6-8402d5e88ff7

.NET:
adb0d065-c0ec-5640-bfd6-8402d5e88ff7

As you might notice they are quite similar, last parts are the same, first parts are using the same digits, only the order of the digits are different. Every UUID that I create the way I explained above, follows the same pattern which makes me think that there's a byte order difference.

How can I create a UUID value in linux and have the same string representation using the same byte array.

Comment: Endianness problem? Didn't you forget to call [`htons`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons)/`ntohs`?

Comment: Ok I omit the network part, I manually entered the same byte array in a small .net application, it still doesn't have the same spring representation. I reversed the byte order, it doesn't generate anything meaningful. therefore it doesn't look like htons is the culprit here.

Comment: from my understanding if you want to have the same string representation between .net and linux, you will need to change the byte order as follows. Original order of the indexes that's generated in linux: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 the order you should use in .net: 4,3,2,1,6,5,8,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16, that will yield the same string.

Comment: After checking a little bit more, I understood that it's endianness problem like you said in the beginning, GUID consists of 4 byte int, 2 byte short, 2 byte short, 8 1 bytes, my linux machine was converting 4 bytes and 2 bytes in the little endian order.

Comment: According to [wiki:GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Binary_encoding), GUIDs have to be encoded as Big-Endian.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this means that the linux's output is right. How do you output the GUID in .net?

Comment: nope my linux output was wrong, certain portions of my uuid byte array was in little endian byte order. namely first 8 bytes of the array(0-3(4 bytes),4-5(2 bytes),6-7(2 bytes)) that was creating the difference. If you convert each portion to big endian before converting them to string, you will have the same result in linux and .net

Comment: Hmm, then how do you output the guid in linux?

Comment: I use uuid_unparse(uuidGenerated, p_pGeneratedUUID); to get a char array from uuid_t type. then  I use printf to output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parted/2002-01/msg00099.html) and [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/pipermail/vbox-dev/2008-August/000723.html) messages, the problem is really in different understanding of whether GUIDs/UUIDs should be Big- or Little-Endian. It looks like Microsoft's implementation treats them as Big-Endian (at least on Intel platforms), but `uuid_unparse` seems to be Little-Endian. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid) says that the GUID (which is Microsoft's UUID) follows [RFC 4122, section 4.1.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt), which seems to demand Big-Endian ordering.

So, this is a clear inconsistency between the implementations. As a workaround, I would propose to exchange the data between the systems in string format, which seems to be consistent across both systems.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't have the same byte array *and* have `Guid.ToString` produce a string that matches the Linux string.

You'll need to decide on which one you want to prioritise:

```
var dotNetGuid = new Guid(new byte[] { 101, 208, 176, 173, 236, 192, 64, 86,
                                       191, 214, 132, 2, 213, 232, 143, 247 });

// option 1 - keep the existing guid's byte array intact
//            and create a new ToUnixString method to display it as-required

Console.WriteLine(dotNetGuid.ToString());      // adb0d065-c0ec-5640-bfd6-8402d5e88ff7
Console.WriteLine(dotNetGuid.ToUnixString());  // 65d0b0ad-ecc0-4056-bfd6-8402d5e88ff7

// option 2 - create a new guid by re-arranging the existing guid's byte array
//            and then use the standard ToString method

var unixGuid = dotNetGuid.ChangeByteOrder();
Console.WriteLine(dotNetGuid.ToString());  // adb0d065-c0ec-5640-bfd6-8402d5e88ff7
Console.WriteLine(unixGuid.ToString());    // 65d0b0ad-ecc0-4056-bfd6-8402d5e88ff7

// ...

public static class GuidExtensions
{
    public static string ToUnixString(this Guid guid,
        string format = "D", IFormatProvider provider = null)
    {
        return guid.ChangeByteOrder().ToString(format, provider);
    }

    public static Guid ChangeByteOrder(this Guid guid)
    {
        var s = guid.ToByteArray();
        var d = new byte[]
                    {
                        s[3], s[2], s[1], s[0], s[5], s[4], s[7], s[6],
                        s[8], s[9], s[10], s[11], s[12], s[13], s[14], s[15]
                    };

        return new Guid(d);
    }
}
```